# Concat suddenly throwing an error

Tags: sql, oracle

After running this query(which worked perfectly fine before we've updated our Oracle version to g11) :

```
SELECT to_char(wm_concat(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE) )  AS COMB , 
       case when   instr( to_char(wm_concat(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE) ), 'T_V') > 0  then 1 else 0  end +
       case when   instr( to_char(wm_concat(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE) ), 'INT') > 0  then 1 else 0  end +
       case when   instr( to_char(wm_concat(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE) ), 'TEL') > 0  then 1 else 0  end category_count 
       ....
FROM ....
```

The actual query is huge and messy, I've managed to spot the things that are causing this error (`COMB,CATEGORY_COUNT` from the query above).

`PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE` is type `VARCHAR2(3)` .

I'm getting an error :

> ORA-22922: non existent LOB value

What is causing this error and why the sudden change after the upgrade ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a row/set of values that causes the problem? I'd suspect a particular value in PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE may be causing the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it, the only three values exist in this column are `T_V,INT,TEL` . @MattGibson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my attempt to answer why this happened.  There are multiple layers to this answer, and as they go deeper they get more speculative.

**Why did my query stop working?**

The query failed because `WM_CONCAT` is an undocumented feature that is not available in your new database.

**Why isn't it available anymore?**

`WM_CONCAT` was used *internally* as part of Oracle Workspace Manager (OWM).  OWM is an *optional* component in 10g and 11g.  Some databases may have been installed without it, or a DBA may have removed it later.  The option does not exist for Express Edition.  And the function does not exist at all in Oracle 12c.

A long time ago, someone on the Internet found the function, thought it was useful, told people, and the idea spread.  But Oracle never told people to use it and never guaranteed it wouldn't disappear some day.  That day has come.

**But... why would this happen with such a popular feature?!**

It's an attitude problem with Oracle corporation.

Oracle does not value features that are clearly useful, if they are also theoretically unnecessary.  They waited twenty years to create a convenient, official function to do something that every database developer in the world does all the time.

You never *needed* to use `WM_CONCAT`.  You could have used hacks with XMLAGG, Oracle Data Cartridge, `MODEL`, `CAST(COLLECT...`, etc.  Those were all terrible solutions, but they did work, so why don't you lazy developers just make your unique solution every time you need to solve a common problem?

That attitude drives me crazy and I see the same thing with simple tasks like string splitting and Boolean types.

For a product that has hints, you'd think Oracle developers would have a better appreciation of the idea of adding features that are useful, even if they maybe aren't theoretically needed.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I'll approve it since it doesn't look like anyone going to provide me any sort of documentation of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this issue by using `LISTAGG()` instead of `WM_CONCAT()` :

```
SELECT to_char(LISTAGG(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE))  AS COMB,
       case when   instr( to_char(LISTAGG(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE)), 'T_V') > 0  then 1 else 0  end +
       case when   instr( to_char(LISTAGG(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE)), 'INT') > 0  then 1 else 0  end +
       case when   instr( to_char(LISTAGG(PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE)), 'TEL') > 0  then 1 else 0  end   category_count
FROM ...
```

But I still haven't figured out WHY - The question remains.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing this. WM_CONCAT() is not supproted.

Comment: What does not supported mean? Why after an upgrade old scripts stop working? `WM_CONCAT()` still does work . This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Note that WM_CONCAT is undocumented and unsupported by Oracle, meaning it should not be used in production systems. The LISTAGG function, which can produce the same output as WM_CONCAT is both documented and supported by Oracle.

Comment: But why does it throw an error if it has the same functionality as `LISTAGG` ? Why does `WM_CONCAT` works on other places? @Sebz

Comment: Since it's not documented I don't know its limitations.